# how to make ocean with depth

Tags: ocean-simulation

[image]

I'm trying to make ocean but I cant to make the ocean had that feeling of depth

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible solution (will only work in cycles):

1. Instead of using a plane, turn your ocean into a volume that
   stretches from the surface to the bottom of the sea.
2. Give it a `Principled BSDF` with perfectly white `Base Color`, `Roughness` set to about 0.0 and `Transmission` somewhere at 1.0 (all values can of course be tweaked at the end)
3. Beneath the surface-tab (where you just set your Principled BSDF) is a volume-tab. Open it, and choose for `Volume` the `Volume Absorption` shader. Set the `Color` to something ocean-ish and tweak the `Density` until you're satisfied.
4. Render and profit!

A little demonstration:

[image]

The red Suzanne is behind the ico-sphere, the spheres material (visible on the right) is something like you'd want your ocean to be. Here's a render:

[image]

The lighting is off but you get the idea. Not only can you see the Suzanne through the sphere, things like refraction, etc. are handled for you automatically.